# Difference between Parallel and Concurrent programming?

Tags: terminology, parallel-computing, concurrency

When looking at concurrent programming, two terms are commonly used i.e. concurrent and parallel.

And some programming languages specifically claim support for parallel programming, such as [Java](http://www.ateji.com/px/whitepapers/Ateji%20PX%20for%20Java%20v1.0.pdf).

Does this means parallel and concurrent programming are actually different?

Comment: Yes, concurrent and parallel programming are different. for instance, you can have two threads (or processes) executing concurrently on the same core through context switching. When the two threads (or processes) are executed on two different cores (or processors), you have parallelism. So, in the former case (concurrency) parallelism is only "virtual", while in the latter you have true parallelism. Therefore, every parallel program is concurrent, but the converse is not necessarily true.

Comment: So simply, it is required to have specific language support for "parallel" programming ? In that case Java Future , Clojure agents etc. can not be considered as "parallel" programming but "concurrent" programming constructs?

Comment: Be careful here. You can achieve the same result either through language support (i.e., extending a language with new constructs) or using a low level approach (e.g., by using a library, as in the case of MPI and OpenMP). Anyway, with current multicore processors and operating systems with SMP support, program that will be concurrent if run on old single-core processors, may be executed in parallel if the OS schedules the threads of execution of the program on different cores. So, the distinction is a little "blurred" nowadays.

Comment: What you use for a speed of light latency constant. In concurrency you pretend speed of light latency is one clock cycle. In parallel you assume one server is next door, in distributed you assume one server is on Mars.

Comment: [Here is Rob Pike talking about concurrency vs parallelism](http://vimeo.com/49718712).

Comment: I removed all but one question now (the one answers focussed more on). If the other (four) questions are still of interest, please open new questions for them. (cc @DaveClarke)

Comment: Robert Harper discusses the issue in two blog posts, ["Parallelism is not concurrency"](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/parallelism-is-not-concurrency/) and ["Parallelism and Concurrency, Revisited"](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2014/04/09/parallelism-and-concurrency-revisited/), which you might want to check.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, outside of the functional programming community, I haven't seen the same distinguishing between parallelism and concurrency.

Answer (score 26):

> Distinguish parallelism (using extra computational units to do more work per unit time) from concurrency (managing access to shared resources). Teach parallelism ﬁrst because it is easier and helps establish a non- sequential mindset.

From " A Sophomoric∗ Introduction to Shared-Memory Parallelism and Concurrency" by
Dan Grossman (version of November 16, 2013)

Answer (score 22):

Conurrency and parallelism differ in the problems they solve and cause, but they are not independent.

#### Concurrency

Executing two tasks *concurrently* means that individual steps of both tasks are executed in an interleaved fashion. If you disregard parallelism, you can assume that only one statement is executed at any point in time, but you have (a priori) no guarantee which task gets to execute the next step.

This is useful in some regards:

- Clearer programming of independent tasks in one program.
- Allows to deal with IO while computing (e.g. in GUI).
- Allows for execution of more than one program at a time (concurrency on OS level).

Some of the main challenges are:

- Maintain data consistency.
- Avoid [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlocks) and [livelocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livelock).
- Determine precise semantics of concurrent processes.
- Determine static properties that ensure correctness.

#### Parallelism

Executing two tasks *in parallel* means that statements are executed *at the same time*. This is mainly useful for:

- Improve system throughput by executing programs in parallel (e.g. on multi core systems).
- Improve runtime of individual programs by utilising multiple CPUs at once.
- Utilise IO on many machines (e.g. distributed databases).

Key challenges include:

- Partition problems that allow and develop algorithms that can employ parallelism.
- Minimise dependencies and communication among the computation units.
- All the problems brought by concurrency: at least from the point of view of memory, parallel programs look like concurrent ones due to serialisation of memory accesses.
- Deal with sub-optimal hardware support.

See also [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/distributed-vs-parallel-computing) for distinguishing parallel and distributed computing.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to Nish's answer, let me recommend Simon Marlow's book on [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929) or his [shorter tutorial](http://community.haskell.org/%7Esimonmar/par-tutorial.pdf).  They answer your first question from Haskell's perspective, so they could be better suited for theoretically inclined readers (Haskell is a purely functional, lazy programming language that is much closer to Mathematics than other languages).

Quoting from there:

> In many fields, the words parallel and concurrent are synonyms; not so
> in programming, where they are used to describe fundamentally
> different concepts.
>
> A parallel program is one that uses a
> multiplicity of computational hardware (e.g. multiple processor cores)
> in order to perform computation more quickly. Different parts of the
> computation are delegated to different processors that execute at the
> same time (in parallel), so that results may be delivered earlier than
> if the computation had been performed sequentially.
>
> In contrast, concurrency is a program-structuring technique in which
> there are multiple threads of control. Notionally the threads of
> control execute "at the same time"; that is, the user sees their
> effects interleaved.  Whether they actually execute at the same time
> or not is an implementation detail; a concurrent program can execute
> on a single processor through interleaved execution, or on multiple
> physical processors.

I recommend reading the rest in the tutorial (p.4), but let me quote some of the remainder of this section, as it connects both programming paradigms with quantitative and qualitative characteristics of programs, such as efficiency, modularity, and determinism.

> While parallel programming is concerned only with efficiency,
> concurrent programming is concerned with structuring a program that
> needs to interact with multiple independent external agents (for
> example the user, a database server, and some external clients).
> Concurrency allows such programs to be modular; the thread that
> interacts with the user is distinct from the thread that talks to the
> database. In the absence of concurrency, such programs have to be
> written with event loops and callbacks --- indeed, event loops and
> callbacks are often used even when concurrency is available, because
> in many languages concurrency is either too expensive, or too
> difficult, to use.
>
> The notion of "threads of control" does not make sense in a purely
> functional program, because there are no effects to observe, and the
> evaluation order is irrelevant. So concurrency is a structuring
> technique for effectful code; in Haskell, that means code in the IO
> monad.
>
> A related distinction is between deterministic and nondeterministic
> programming models. A deterministic programming model is one in which
> each program can give only one result, whereas a nondeterministic
> programming model admits programs that may have different results,
> depending on some aspect of the execution. Concurrent programming
> models are necessarily nondeterministic, because they must interact
> with external agents that cause events at unpredictable times.
> Nondeterminism has some notable drawbacks, however: programs become
> signifficantly harder to test and reason about.
>
> For parallel programming we would like to use deterministic
> programming models if at all possible. Since the goal is just to
> arrive at the answer more quickly, we would rather not make our
> program harder to debug in the process. Deterministic parallel
> programming is the best of both worlds: testing, debugging and
> reasoning can be performed on the sequential program, but the program
> runs faster when processors are added. Indeed, most computer
> processors themselves implement deterministic parallelism in the form
> of pipelining and multiple execution units.
>
> While it is possible to do parallel programming using concurrency,
> that is often a poor choice, because concurrency sacriffices
> determinism. In Haskell, the parallel programming models are
> deterministic. However, it is important to note that deterministic
> programming models are not sufficient to express all kinds of parallel
> algorithms; there are algorithms that depend on internal
> nondeterminism, particularly problems that involve searching a
> solution space. In Haskell, this class of algorithms is expressible
> only using concurrency.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly idealised answer, perhaps...

- *Concurrency* is a property of how a program is **written**. If a program is written using constructions like forks/joins, locks, transactions, atomic compare-and-swap operations, and so on, then it is concurrent.
- *Parallelism* is a property of how a program **executes**. If a program executes on more than one computational unit simultaneously, then it is executing in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of answers on this, but it can be confusing. I like to think of it this way, and maybe it helps?:

***Concurrent programming*** is code that does not care about the order of execution. Java is a poor language for concurrent programming, but there are libraries and frameworks to help. JavaScript is an excellent language for concurrent programming, and it's often difficult when you want to write something that *isn't* concurrent (e.g., if you want to force the order of execution). Concurrent programming is great for event-driven programming (where order of execution is determined by event listeners, like code running in your browser that acts when you click a button or type into a box).

An example would include creating a hundred HTTP requests. In NodeJS, the simplest solution is to open all 100 requests at once with a callback method, and when the responses come back, a method is executed each time. That's concurrent programming. In Ruby, the simplest (most common) solution is to open a request and handle the response, open the next request and handle the response, etc. For many requests, NodeJS is easier to do in a timely fashion, although you have to be careful to avoid hammering the server or maxing out your outbound connections (easy to do by mistake). You can write the Ruby in a concurrent way, but it's not how most Ruby code is written, and it hurts a little to do it.

***Parallel programming*** is code that can be run simultaneously in multiple threads or processes. This allows you to optimise performance by running the code across multiple CPUs (often including multiple machines, as you might with something like Akka). Because NodeJS is not multi-threaded and there's no parallel execution, you don't have to worry about writing threadsafe code (and most JavaScript code I've seen is not threadsafe) . In Java, even though the language doesn't make concurrent programming the normal pattern, parallel programming is very much built in, and you do often have to worry about thread-safety. If you are writing a Website in Java, typically this will be run in a container that runs each request in a separate thread in the same memory, so anything shared across requests in memory (such as an in-memory cache or configuration) must be thread-safe.

---

Some of the above depends on the scope and boundaries you are talking about. I work on Websites. Most Java code I see is not concurrent programming. Sure, if you zoom out enough, the order that the customer requests come in is not important, but if you zoom in any further than that, the order that things are executed is dictated by the code. But the code is written so that the requests can execute in parallel with lots of shared objects that must be thread-safe.

Meanwhile, most JavaScript code I see is concurrent: it is written in way that the order of execution is unimportant at many levels. But it is not written to support parallel execution in shared memory. Sure, you can execute the same code in parallel across multiple processes, but the objects are not shared, so it is not parallel programming in any meaningful sense.

For additional reading, I do really like the illustrations in the top answer to this question here: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-parallel-concurrent-and-asynchronous-programming